# How to fetch multiple records by using the list of embedded primary key in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have specific requirement where I have 2 primary keys in a table.
I am using @EmbeddedId and @Embeddable class to declare those primary keys.

Now I am struck with inserting and fetching the multiple primary key at once to and from DB using JPA.

Is there a way in JPA like Embedded ElementCollection which I can use to retrieve the multiple records using list of primary key?

For clarity, this is what I have :
Table columns : col1, col2, col3 ect..
Here col1 and col2 are the primary keys and both needs to accept the values in list and also needs to return the multiple list and col3 and other columns can have same value for all those.

Consider I have class TableA and primary embedded class TablePK..

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_A")
public class TableA implements Serializable {
@EmbeddedId

    private TablePK primaryKey; 
    private String colC;

    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "colA", column = @Column(name = "FUND_ID")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "colB", column = @Column(name = "CNTRY_CDE"))
    })
    public TablePK getPrimaryKey() {
        return primaryKey;
    }
    public void setPrimaryKey(TablePK primaryKey) {
        this.primaryKey = primaryKey;
    }

    @Column(name="COL_C")
    public String getColC(){
        return colC;
    }
    public void setColC(String colC) {
        this.colC=colC;
    }
}


@Embeddable
public class TablePK implements Serializable
{
    private List<String> colA;
    private List<String> colB;

    public List<String> getColA(){
        return colA;
    }
    public void setColA(List<String> colA) {
        this.colA=colA;
    }

    public List<String> getColB(){
        return colB;
    }
    public void setColB(List<String> colB) {
        this.colB=colB;
    }   
}
```

Does something like ElementCollection would work here to insert multiple records of primary keys and also to retrieve multiple records.
I know it will work with if we have primary and secondary table but in this case it is a single table and also on primary keys.

Comment: A "List" cannot be part of a PK.

Comment: got it, Thank you.